# Remove jsessionid from url Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, url-rewriting

I'm using spring boot to make my app and run it on tomcat 10 server. But the jsessionid show on my url. I've tried using tuckey rewrite filter, but it's don't work. jsessionid just display when the first time I access to my app, and this problem just happen on my ubuntu server, no localhost. This is my code:
urlrewrite.xml:
`

```
 <outbound-rule encodefirst="true">

    <note>Remove jsessionid from embedded urls - for urls WITH query parameters</note>

    <from>^/(.*);jsessionid=.*[?](.*)$</from>

    <to encode="false">/$1?$2</to>

</outbound-rule>

<outbound-rule encodefirst="true">

    <note>Remove jsessionid from embedded urls - for urls WITHOUT query parameters</note>

    <from>^/(.*);jsessionid=.*[^?]$</from>

    <to encode="false">/$1</to>

</outbound-rule>


<!--

INSTALLATION

    in your web.xml add...

    <filter>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
            <param-value>WARN</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

 EXAMPLES

 Redirect one url
    <rule>
        <from>/some/old/page.html</from>
        <to type="redirect">/very/new/page.html</to>
    </rule>

Redirect a directory
    <rule>
        <from>/some/olddir/(.*)</from>
        <to type="redirect">/very/newdir/$1</to>
    </rule>

Clean a url
    <rule>
        <from>/products/([0-9]+)</from>
        <to>/products/index.jsp?product_id=$1</to>
    </rule>
eg, /products/1234 will be passed on to /products/index.jsp?product_id=1234 without the user noticing.

Browser detection
    <rule>
        <condition name="user-agent">Mozilla/[1-4]</condition>
        <from>/some/page.html</from>
        <to>/some/page-for-old-browsers.html</to>
    </rule>
eg, will pass the request for /some/page.html on to /some/page-for-old-browsers.html only for older
browsers whose user agent srtings match Mozilla/1, Mozilla/2, Mozilla/3 or Mozilla/4.

Centralised browser detection
    <rule>
        <condition name="user-agent">Mozilla/[1-4]</condition>
        <set type="request" name="browser">moz</set>
    </rule>
eg, all requests will be checked against the condition and if matched
request.setAttribute("browser", "moz") will be called.

-->
```

` 
config:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomUrlRewriteFilter extends UrlRewriteFilter {
 private static final String CONFIG_LOCATION = "classpath:/urlrewrite.xml";
 
    @Value(CONFIG_LOCATION)
    private Resource resource;
@Override
protected void loadUrlRewriter(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    try {
        Conf conf1 = new Conf(filterConfig.getServletContext(), resource.getInputStream(), resource.getFilename(), "");
        checkConf(conf1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }
}
```

}

Help me please!